# Best approach to upgrade MVC3 web app to MVC5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web application which runs on Azure which is currently running MVC3/C#, EF6.1, .NET4.5. I would like to upgrade it to MVC5 to be:

a) Current

b) Get benefit of new features

c) Get Performance gains.

This is a part of a performance project, so hopefully there will be performance gains from doing this, especially with the upgrade to Razor 2.

What would be the recommended upgrade approach to MVC5? Should I upgrade to MVC4 to start with, then go from MVC4 to MVC5, or straight to 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a handy documented guide by Rick Anderson which he wrote to upgrade from MVC4, the same applies to you with the exception of the fact that the "Old version" of DLLs he mentions will be different to the ones that you will have, but the outcome will still be the same.

You can find the guide [HERE](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

Comment: Thank you for this. Do I assume from your answer that it is perfectly fine to go from MVC3 to MVC5, without first going to MVC4? Also would you expect significant performance gains particularly with the rendering?

Comment: @SamJolly Yep that should be fine, just back everything up before you do just as a precautionary measure. There are numerous feature differences in terms of 3 vs 5, whilst it won't guarantee a noticeable performance improvement to your site, you'd expect at least some gains plus the additional features you have to work with.